# Multiple HTML tag data parsing in PHP using TagName

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing

I am having data like this in HTML file. I dont know how to extract this data using TagName. Please help me out.

I have tried with the following code.http://www.phpro.org/examples/Parse-HTML-With-PHP-And-DOM.html, But it is not working for me.

Comment: We're not here to go through all you're code or magically give you the final end product you're trying to reach. We'll gladly look through isolated issues and help you through steps in achieving the end product, though... don't expect anyone to respond to this.

Comment: yeah I agree with you., could you help me with the logic :(

Comment: I didn't mean to be that subtle (if you really didn't understand what I was trying to say), but: isolate the code you need. Give us one example of what you want to scrape and be very specific. Don't give us over 15-20+ lines of useless infomration

Comment: Thanks. Example//I need to extract all the <td>Data1<td> Values. from the entire page.

Comment: No... update your post and get rid of all the useless information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't installed the PHP DOM extension.
You'd better print out the error report!

Comment: Hi Kaijian,

 $dom = new domDocument; 

    /*** load the html into the object ***/ 
    $dom->loadHTML($html); 

    /*** discard white space ***/ 
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

    /*** the table by its tag name ***/ 
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

This is working for simple HTML parsing, But I have lot Tables inside my Div, it have no element ID. Help me out.

Comment: you can use regular expressions to parse the html or try https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/